# Script Not Copying Cell Value to K5 as Expected

Tags: google-apps-script

I've developed a script based on a concept: when I click on a specific cell that I've defined in the Apps Script, the value from that cell should be copied to cell K5.

I'm uncertain about why it's not functioning as expected, and there's no error message provided. I would greatly appreciate your assistance in identifying and resolving the issue. Your help is valued.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var sheetName = "Calendar"; // Replace with the actual sheet name
  
  // Define your dynamic calendar ranges here
  var calendarRanges = [
    sheetName + "!B7:H7",
    sheetName + "!B13:H13",
    sheetName + "!B19:H19",
    sheetName + "!B25:H25",
    sheetName + "!B31:H31",
    sheetName + "!B37:H37"
  ]; // Add your ranges here
  
  // Check if the edited cell is within any of the defined calendar ranges
  for (var i = 0; i < calendarRanges.length; i++) {
    var rangeData = sheet.getRange(calendarRanges[i]);
    if (
      range.getRow() >= rangeData.getRow() &&
      range.getRow() <= rangeData.getLastRow() &&
      range.getColumn() == rangeData.getColumn()
    ) {
      sheet.getRange("K5").setValue(range.getValue());
      break; // Stop checking after finding a matching range
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const rows = [7, 13, 19, 25, 31, 37];
  const idx = rows.indexOf(e.range.rowStart);
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart > 1 && e.range.columnStart < 9 && ~idx) {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1")
    sh.getRange("K5").setValue(e.value);
  }
}


function onSelectionChange(e) {
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  //e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const rows = [7, 13, 19, 25, 31, 37];
  const idx = rows.indexOf(e.range.rowStart);
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart > 1 && e.range.columnStart < 9 && ~idx) {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1")
    sh.getRange("K5").setValue(e.range.getValue());
  }
}
```

Event object for onSelectionChange()

```
{"user":{"email":"","nickname":""},"authMode":"LIMITED","source":{},"range":{"columnEnd":,"columnStart":,"rowEnd":,"rowStart":}}
```

Comment: your assistance is greatly appreciated! The solution is functioning perfectly. Just to clarify, I'm aiming to achieve this functionality with a single click, without the need to edit the cell. I tried with `onSelectionChange`  but nothing worked

Comment: You wont be able to do it with just a click because onSelectionChange does provide the same event object that onEdit does

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this using a single click or this thing does not exist for Google Sheets.

Comment: Hold on I just check the event object and they seem to have added more to it than I thought let me check it out

Comment: I  just checked and with a minor change it does work with onSelectionChange

Comment: So yes with one click you can copy the current value into K5

Comment: thank you for the help @Cooper i appreciate it. Should I set up a trigger to make it operational, or will it function without one?

Comment: Just post the code into the script editor and save it.  Then close the spreadsheet and open it again.  Anyway that's what I have to do to get the onSelectionChange trigger to work for me.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's functioning as intended. I greatly appreciate your assistance!

Comment: I have one more favor to ask! Yesterday, I left the sheet and it was working fine. But today, when I opened it and clicked on the dates to paste them into specific cells, it didn't work. So, I went back to the script, saved the project again, and then it started working. question is? Why did the code stop working? Do I need to perform this action daily? @Cooper